# JBOSS: /status & /status?XML=true & /status?full=true disable

Tags: jboss

I need to resolve one security request in my company and in summary is:

We have an internal domain like ""https://customer.domaincorp.com"" from a Jboss server and we need to disable the possibility to use (from final users) the information provided in:

1. /status
2. /status?XML=true
3. /status?full=true

I´ve been ivestigating in different forums but I am stuck.

How can I disable these website extensions?

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: I am using jboss-4.0.5.GA (if I am not wrong).

Comment: Ok, that explains it - that's 14 year old software.  I found [a link](http://sekar-linux.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-disable-status-page-for-jboss.html) that tells you how to remove it.  I believe that this page hasn't existed for about a decade or so.